# Access Instance variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function, I am trying to access the instance variable. But it's giving me some error. How can I access instance variable in Javascript ? I tried below method, but not working

```
function Test(){
   var a=10;
}

var test=new Test();
test.a=20;
```

For some reason I don't want to go with the following way:

```
var Test={
  a:''
}
```

Comment: That is a local variable, you cannot access it directly. Use `this.a=10` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared `a` as a variable local to that function, so there is no way to access it outside (as you currently have it)
If you want `a` to be an instance variable attach it to the object

```
function Test(){
   this.a=10;
}

var test=new Test();
test.a=20;
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3C8BK/), at least in Chrome v32, seems to show that using `var` syntax still allows one to access the variable using from outside the object using `test.a`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Divey That's because you are creating a new property, not modifying the existing variable. See http://jsfiddle.net/3C8BK/1/

Comment: @JuanMendes Whoops! Indeed I am.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this :

```
function Test(){
    this.a=10;
}
```

Here a good documentation on the subject : [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers tell you how to do it by making `a`  a public property. If you really need a private variable, use the following code. The main reason you would use this instead of a public property is to prevent callers from setting `a` to invalid values.

```
function Test() {
   var a = 10;
   this.setA = function(val) {
        a = val; 
   };
   this.getA = function(val) {
        return a; 
   };
}

var t = new Test();
t.setA(80);
t.getA(); // 80
```